# GetListItems on document library not returning items within folders

Tags: 2010, jquery, spservices

I'm using SPServices to run a `GetListItems` query on a particular document library. This is in implementing a custom metadata-driven search for lists/libraries.  In cases when the document library contains folders, the results are typically including the folder, but none of the items underneath of that folder, e.g.:

```
 <z:row ows_Title='My Nifty Subfolder' ows_LinkFilename='My Nifty Subfolder' ows_Author='23;#Bob Smith' ows_Modified='2015-02-05 09:32:42' ows_ContentType='Folder' ows_Created='2015-02-05 09:32:42' />
```

Is there some special CAML incantation that is needed to make the result include files within subfolders?   At present, I am already using a CAMLQuery that looks like this, so if I'm making an error here, feedback is appreciated:

```
<Where>
  <Or>
   <Contains><FieldRef Name='ows_Title'/><Value Type='Text'>my search term here</Value></Contains>
  <Or>
   <Contains><FieldRef Name='ows_LinkFilename'/><Value Type='Text'>my search term here</Value></Contains>
  <Or>
   <Contains><FieldRef Name='ows_Description1'/><Value Type='Text'>my search term here</Value></Contains>
  <Or>
   <Contains><FieldRef Name='ows_Team'/><Value Type='Text'>my search term here</Value></Contains>
  <Or>
   <Contains><FieldRef Name='ows_Editor'/><Value Type='Text'>my search term here</Value></Contains>
   <Contains><FieldRef Name='ows_Keywords'/><Value Type='Text'>my search term here</Value></Contains>
  </Or></Or></Or></Or></Or></Where>
```

I'm also aware that this deeply nested `<Or>` construct is ugly, but experimentation and other questions have generally indicated that `<Or>` only takes two arguments, so I don't know of another way to express this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you need to place following query option

```
CAMLQueryOptions: "<QueryOptions><ViewAttributes Scope="Recursive"/></QueryOptions>"
```